# Runtime error after updating Fullcalendar to 2.2.3

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I'm updating an app to use the latest version of Fullcalendar (2.2.3).  I was using 1.6.4.

Upon updating to the current version, I'm getting a runtime error when fullcalendar tries to prepare for retrieving the event data.  When it hits the function below, the rangeStart and rangeEnd variables are null and when the .clone() method is applied, a null reference is generated.  Below is the function in fullcalendar.js (starts at line 1401) where the error occurs.

```
    function _fetchEventSource(source, callback) {
    var i;
    var fetchers = fc.sourceFetchers;
    var res;

    for (i=0; i<fetchers.length; i++) {
        res = fetchers[i].call(
            t, // this, the Calendar object
            source,
            rangeStart.clone(),  <== rangeStart is null and causes null reference error here
            rangeEnd.clone(),
            options.timezone,
            callback
        );

        if (res === true) {
            // the fetcher is in charge. made its own async request
            return;
        }
        else if (typeof res == 'object') {
            // the fetcher returned a new source. process it
            _fetchEventSource(res, callback);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Here is how the calendar object is defined in my view

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: false,
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: '@Url.Action("PullCalendarEvents")',
                type: 'POST',
                error: function () {
                    //alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                    presentErrorPopup('fetch');
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

The calendar is in a tab.  This is the line that is called to display the calendar when the tab is selected.

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')
```

Do I need to change the way the calendar object is defined or called?

Comment: This is purely JavaScript and has nothing to do with C#. I updated the tags accordingly.

Comment: True, the code is JavaScript, but I'm using it within a c# app.  You gave it a - for that?

Comment: No I didn't downvote. Just edited your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by changing the order of the references to .fullCalendar in the view.  Apparently, the order didn't matter in version 1.6.4, but version 2.2.3 didn't like it.

```
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: false,
            eventSources: [
            {
                url: '@Url.Action("PullCalendarEvents")',
                type: 'POST',
                error: function () {
                    //alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                    presentErrorPopup('fetch');
                }
            }
        ]
    });

//Moving this section to be below the above code resolved the error
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            show: function (event, ui) {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case missed semicolon was the reason

**"Type Error: rangeStart is null"** (or "A is null" if minified):

```
var reloadCalendar = function()
{
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
}

(function()
{
...
})();
```

**No error:**

```
var reloadCalendar = function()
{
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
};

(function()
{
...
})();
```

Maybe this helps.